# C++ equiv to C# value keyword

Tags: c#, c++

Hi I'm defining a class within  C++  I came across a situation in that Is it possible to do some form of say this code: (using the `value` keyword)

```
total = balance + value;
```

within C++ i have looked through the syntax and noticed that there is no `value` keyword, so is there a standard equivalent to this that I would need to define?

Comment: Do you mean the `var` keyword?

Comment: @TankorSmash what's the var keyword?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Comment: You can just extra pass a parameter called `value`.

Comment: I think it mean **value** keyword of properties in C#, in C++ you could treat properties simulations (because C++ don't has properties per se) as inline `long& getX() {return _x;}` and accesing like this `a.getX() += 5;`, `a.getX() = a.getX() + expression;`, etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `value` keyword in C# is used for properties. Since C++ does not have properties, there is no equivalent keyword there.

Comment: @CatLikeOlive0, you should mark this as the answer if you think it's the correct answer.